# Meteor / Websocket API - Show live data from API

Tags: meteor

Still quite new to meteor/coding and I have a question on how to connect meteor to a live api that uses websocket.

The api is from bittrex (exchange for cryptocurrency) and there is a node js package that gives a "subscribtion" to the api in order to get live data:

https://github.com/dparlevliet/node.bittrex.api

I manage to have it run with node with no problem but I would ideally like to connect it to Meteor in order to present the data nicely. The props should be updated live with the data received. (nb: there is a lot of data, it is continuously coming).

Is there a good way to do this or is meteor not suitable for this. It means the props would change continuously.

Would a node/react solution only be better ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question might get closed because it's a bit opinion based but...

You have a streaming data source providing data over ws. You could:

(a) have all your clients subscribe directly to that source and not involve your server at all. In this case you'd be just using React on the client and basically ignoring Meteor (even though you'd be building the UI in a Meteor app). I don't know how bitrex charges for access or how they scale across many connections so that may be an issue if there are many connections.

(b) use your Meteor app to proxy then fan-out the bitrex data. In this case you would:

1. subscribe to the bitrex data source *from your server*
2. *copy* the data into a mongo *collection*
3. *publish* that data using a Meteor *publication*.
4. Your clients would *subscribe* to the Meteor publication and on the front end you would get reactive data updates like any other Meteor app.

The benefits of (b) are that bitrex only sees one subscriber and your app looks like a pretty vanilla Meteor app. Also if you have to use any kind of api key or secret to access bitrex then that key doesn't need to be shared with the client side.